# Replacing ArrayAccess with MethodInvocation in JDT

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I need to transform

```
xyz[3].aaa[1].bbb[2].jjj
```

to

```
getXyz(3).getAaa(1).getBbb(2).getJjj()
```

using `JDT` core.

Replace `ArrayAccess` with some getter Method does not help because the array access visited are as follows:-

```
xyz[3].aaa[1].bbb[2]
xyz[3].aaa[1]
xyz[3]
```

So replacing just the ArrayAccess to getter will loose some replacements.

Another option I tried is to visit `FieldAccess` but doing that I am left with something like

```
getXyz(3).getAaa(1)[1].getBbb(2)[2].getJjj()
```

Is there a way to replace the [1] or [2] or rather is there was to parse and get hold of just the aaa[1], bbb[2] to remove or replace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to my own question. Short answer is that in the expression `xyz[3].aaa[1]` the `xyz[3].aaa` needs to be treated as an array with index expression as `1` so that the `aaa[1]` or the `[1]` gets accounted for properly.

However programatically I found following approach much easier to deal with.
The approach is to treat the array expression in here as method invocation by simple replacement `replace("\"", "").replace("+", "").replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')')` the problem reduces to renaming the methods.

```
@Test
public void testArray() throws Exception {
    String testExpr = "xyz[3].aaa[1].bbb[2]";

    Document document;
    ASTParser parser;
    parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_EXPRESSION);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    String exprString = testExpr.replace("\"", "").replace("+", "").replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')');

    document = new Document(exprString);
    parser.setSource(document.get().toCharArray());
    Object o = parser.createAST(null);

    if (o instanceof CompilationUnit) {
        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) o;
        IProblem[] problems = cu.getProblems();
        System.err.println(problems);
    }
    Expression expr = (Expression) o;
    final ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(expr.getAST());
    final AST ast = expr.getAST();
    final TextEditGroup textEdits = new TextEditGroup("test");

    expr.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        @Override
        public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
            String getter = getGetter(node.getName().getIdentifier().toString());

            rewriter.replace(node.getName(), 
                    ast.newSimpleName(getter),
                    textEdits);
            return super.visit(node);
        }


    });

    TextEdit edits = rewriter.rewriteAST(document, null);
    edits.apply(document);

    assertEquals("getXyz(3).getAaa(1).getBbb(2)", 
            document.get());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's difficult to do all of the changes in one pass, the simplest and "best to understand" solution would be to break up your code changes into several passes. By one pass I mean:

1. parse the AST
2. do changes that don't overwrite themselves
3. apply the edits

So this means that you would re-parse the code for every pass. The downside of this is that the performance will go down quite a bit.

One way to break your changes into multiple passes could be to find all the array declarations first and then do the changes only for this array.

Comment: Multiple passes will mean I have to call it as many times as the nesting/depth. I would not know. But I could just run it 10 times. I went with following a crude approach....replaced [] with () using generic regex   so that `xyz[3].aaa[1].bbb[2].jjj` becomes `xyz(3).aaa(1).bbb(2).jjj`

Comment: In your example, xyz[] must be declared somewhere. It could be a parameter or it could be a variable declaration (i.e. String[] xyz;). You could look for these declarations first and then go from there.

Comment: Yes. That would make such replacement a bit robust.